# Specialize C++ member function based on class template argument

Tags: c++, templates, boost, overloading, enable-if

I have a class with a template parameter which should decide which of two styles of data it contains.  Based on that parameter I want to implement a member function one of two different ways.  I tried using Boost Enable-If, but without success.  Here's the version of the code that I'm most surprised doesn't work:

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
enum PadSide { Left, Right };
template <int> struct dummy { dummy(int) {} };

template <PadSide Pad>
struct String
{
    typename boost::enable_if_c<Pad ==  Left, void>::type
        getRange(dummy<0> = 0) {}
    typename boost::enable_if_c<Pad == Right, void>::type
        getRange(dummy<1> = 0) {}
};

int main()
{
    String<Left> field;
    field.getRange();
}
```

To this, g++ 4.6.0 says:

```
no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::enable_if_c<false, void>’
```

Of course, the second overload is supposed to not work, but it's supposed to be ignored due to SFINAE.  If I remove the dummy function parameters, g++ says this:

```
‘typename boost::enable_if_c<(Pad == Right), void>::type
    String<Pad>::getRange()‘
cannot be overloaded with
‘typename boost::enable_if_c<(Pad == Left), void>::type
    String<Pad>::getRange()‘
```

Which is why I put the dummy parameters there in the first place--following the Compiler Workarounds section of [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html).

Basically what I want is to have two implementations of getRange(), and have one or the other be selected based on the Pad type.  I was hoping that Enable-If would let me do it without making auxiliary classes to delegate the work to (which I'm going to try in the meantime).

Comment: SFINAE isn't working because it only works with templates. Those functions are not template functions - they're just members of a template class.

Comment: You can make the constructor as an template function by add an template type T, and assign it's default value as `Pad`, but seam VS doesn't support default argument for template function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are going to be making two different versions of `getRange()` anyways, you can always overload your `struct String` member functions depending on the type of `PadSide`.  I know it's not as "pretty", but in the end, it's still a similar amount of code, and you won't have to make multiple class types.

```
template<PadSide Pad>
struct String
{
    void getRange();
};

template<>
void String<Right>::getRange() { /*....*/ }

template<>
void String<Left>::getRange() { /*....*/ }
```

Comment: Awesome.  I was trying to do something like this earlier, but got the syntax/approach a bit wrong.  Thank you.